# Exporting firebase Cloud Firestore data to other file in project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show some information from my users (name for example) on their user page but when I retrieve it from my Firestore in one file and then imports it in the user page-file the data shows as "undefined" and I can't figure out why. I am using Ionic React and TypeScript.

Here is my firebaseConfig.ts file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
 //config stuff
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });


export function setUpProfile() {

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (user != null) {
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
      var fn = doc.data()?.firstname;
      console.log(fn)
      return fn
    })

  }
  else {
    let error = "ej inloggad" as string
    return error

  }

}
```

and here is the user page file "Profile.tsx"

```
import { IonContent, IonGrid, IonIcon, IonLabel, IonRow, IonSegment, IonSegmentButton, IonText, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import { personCircleOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SettingsBtn from '../components/EditProfile';
import {setUpProfile} from '../firebaseConfig'


const Profile: React.FC = () => {

var fn = setUpProfile()
console.log(fn)

    return (
          <IonContent>
              <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
            <IonIcon size="large" color="tertiary" icon={personCircleOutline}/>
            <IonText id='profcont'> </IonText>
          </IonRow>
          <SettingsBtn/>
         <IonRow>
           <IonToolbar>
         <IonSegment onIonChange={e => console.log('Segment selected', e.detail.value)}>
          <IonSegmentButton value="helper">
            <IonLabel>Helper</IonLabel>
          </IonSegmentButton>
          <IonSegmentButton value="receiver">
            <IonLabel>Receiver</IonLabel>
          </IonSegmentButton>
         </IonSegment>
         </IonToolbar>
         </IonRow>
         </IonGrid>
         </IonContent>
  );
  }

  export default Profile;
```

Comment: Your `setUpProfile` function implicitly returns undefined. To return a useful payload (e.g. firstname) you need to refactor the function with callbacks or promises.
P.S. sharing your private apiKey publicly is not a good idea.

Comment: Yup, are you also able to see what the output is from the `console.log`? It could also be something as simple as `firstname` being non-existent in the current context of `doc`